# Is it possible to grab a locator from webdriver exception text?

Tags: python, selenium, theory

I'm running into some issues when automating some tests - mainly the WebDriverException that the click will be captured by a different object. I can solve the issue by using a webdriverwait for the element to disappear - it's a sliding success message displayed in a modal, but the exception message got me thinking; instead of using an explicit wait, is it possible to catch the exception, parse the text and extract some identifiable information of the object and then use it in an webdriverwait on the method?

So for example, if I'm doing this:

```
self.wait_for_success_modal_to_disappear(context)
self.element_is_clickable(context, mark_as_shipped).click()
```

It'll work, but if I comment out the wait method, it'll fail with error message:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at
point (x, y). Other element would receive the click: <div class="success-modal">...</div>
```

What I'm thinking of is modifying the `element_is_clickable` method to include exception handling in a reusable method based on the exception text, sort of like this:

```
def element_is_clickable(self, context, locator):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 15).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
                )
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 15).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)
                )
        return context.driver.find_element(*locator)
    except WebDriverException:
        error_message = repr(traceback.print_exc())
        modal_class_name = <<method to grab everything between the quotation marks>>
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 15).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, modal_class_name))
        )
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 15).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
            )
        WebDriverWait(context.driver, 15).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)
            )
        return context.driver.find_element(*locator)
```

Now, I know this isn't the correct way to handle this, since the error is on the click() not in identifying the element, but I'm mostly interested in the possibility of capturing and parsing the exception message and using that data in a useful way. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until object, that could capture click, disappeared with condition `until_not` like

```
import re

try:
    # click already defined element, e.g. button
    element.click()
except WebDriverException as e:
    # in case of captured click parse exception for this div locator
    xpath = '//div[@%s]' % re.search('class="\w+"', e.args[0]).group() # this is just a simple example of how to handle e.args[0] (exception message string) with regular expressions- you can handle it as you want to
    # wait until modal disappear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    # click again
    element.click()
```